# Android: Animation is reapeting while AnimationListener is implemented

Tags: android, android-animation

In my Android app, I want to start an animation on a View after another View animation is finished. So I used AnimationListener and used the override method onAnimationEnd().
But the problem is when 1st View's animation is fnished, both of the 1st and 2nd View starts to animate. That means the 1st View repeats it's animation with the 2nd animation.

```
    final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Home.this,R.anim.myanimation);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                image_2.startAnimation(anim);
            }

                    @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
   image_1.startAnimation(anim);
```

I want the animation of image_2 will start after the animation of image_1. But image_1 will not repeats it's animation. That the animation will happen sequentially. How to do that?

my animation code is given below:

```
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"    android:fillEnabled="true"  android:fillAfter="true"   android:startOffset="5000">


        <scale android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"   android:fromYScale="1.0"    android:toYScale="1.0"      android:pivotX="100%"  android:duration="8000"   />

    </set>
```

Comment: startAnimation sets the animation to a view and start it. image_2.startAnimation sets the animation to image_2 and starts it for both 1 and 2. use image_1.setAnimation(null) before starting the second animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you should need to implement two listeners. When you call image2 animation initially the animation happens and after at the end of animation listener the animation happens again so the animation will take-place two times.So setting up two listeners and two separate animations for two image view may solve your problem...